# subplots in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I am using Jupyter lab to to work with images and plots. First I create a subplot where i want an image and a graph displayed next to each other. The problem is that is graph plot is much larger than the image and I would like them to be the same size. At least I would like the height of the image and the plot to be the same size.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (image1, plot1) = plt.subplots(figsize=(fig_height, fig_width), nrows=1, ncols=2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1, 1]})
plt.ylim(3888,0)
image1.imshow(original_image)
plot1.plot(x_vals, y_vals_left, x_vals, y_vals_right);
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
plot1.set_aspect(1)
```

That did the job